# Time Complexity Calculation

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity

I'm currently working a few exam question, and got stuck at this point. I am given that a Quicksort algorithm has a time complexity of `O(nlog(n))`. For a particular input size, the time to sort the list is 4 minutes. The question proceeds to ask how long will it take to sort a list of twice the size, on the same system.

I have already ruled out the the time isn't `8` minutes (twice the input size = twice the duration, very very wrong reasoning).

Some working I did:

**Working A**

- `4 = nlog(n)`
- `4 = log(n^n)`
- `16 = n^n`
- I got basically stuck at this point.

**Working B**

- `X = 2nlog(2n) >> 2n` since double the input
- `X = 2n(1 + log(n))`
- `X = 2n + 2nlog(n) >> nlog(n)` was `4` minutes
- `X = 2n + 2(4) = 2n + 8`
- I once again got stuck at this point.

Comment: Actually quicksort is O(n^2) the name is just confusing

Comment: @pseudoDust: his assumption may be wrong. if you look at the problem he assumed something that may influence his solution

Comment: @Pooya " I am **given** that a Quicksort algorithm has a time complexity of O(nlog(n))"

Comment: Actually, there are quick sort implementations that run in O(n log(n)), for example if they use  the median of a sequence as pivotal element. What I find interesting is the actual question, could you state the exact problem text? This sounds like a very vague question to ask...

Comment: @Pooya that time complexity was given in the exam question, I have no control over that. However, the given time complexity is correct for a Best Case or Average Case scenario. The time complexity you quoted, O(n^2) is for a Worst Case scenario.

Comment: @pseudoDust: mergesort, timesort and heapsort has O(nlogn) not quicksort: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: @Pachelbel yep, the time complexity on quicksort varies depending on how the pivot is selected - example if you choose the left most pivot, and the you happen to have a partially sorted list, you'll end up with a worst case scenario of O(n^2).

Comment: What I mean is that if you choose your pivotal element in each step as the median of the elements, you can prove that the worst-case runtime is actually in O(n*log(n)). See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Selection-based_pivoting. Could you state the exact problem text? This seems to be relevant here.

Comment: The question is as follows: The quicksort algorithm has a time complexity of O(nlogn). For a given problem set, assume the quicksort algorithm takes 4 minutes to sort a given list. Approximately how long will it take the algorithm to solve a problem that is two times as large on the same computer? (4 marks)

Comment: I see :) Is it multiple choice?

Comment: No it is not, requires working - I dont think the working is complex math wise, since this exam is strictly a no calculator computing a level exam.

Comment: I think for this problem a corrector of your exam would have to accept almost every solution provided, since the question is not really well-formed. Just a worst-case complexity given in Landau notation, not even the actual coefficients are known - the actual complexity could be something like 4*n*log(n) - sqrt(2*n) + 100000*n ... So all you might do is to "assume" that the actual complexity is actual the function n*log(n) (or even n*ld(n), which seems more reasonable ;-) )

Comment: @Pachelbel that would seem to be the case...but aha, the corrector does what he wants! the examination board wrote in it's report that it found it rather "disappointing that hardly anyone got this question correct" - I wonder why, judging that it's out of syllabus in the first place...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the first thing to notice about this problem is that, given it took 4 minutes to sort the numbers, `n` must be quite large. For instance, I just used quicksort to sort a billion numbers on my computer, and it took just under 3 minutes. So `n` is probably approximately 1 billion (give or take an order of magnitude).

Given that `n` is huge, it is likely reasonable to approximate this runtime as `c*n*lg(n)` for some constant `c`, since the lower-order terms of the runtime expansion shouldn't be too relevant for such a large `n`. If we double `n`, we get the following multiplier of runtime compared to the original runtime:

```
[Runtime(2n)] / [Runtime(n)]
[c * (2n) * lg(2n)] / [c * n * lg(n)]
2 * lg(2n) / lg(n)
2 * log_n(2n)
2 * (1 + log_n(2))
```

Here, `lg()` is the logarithm under an arbitrary base and `log_n()` is the log base `n`.

First, since we assumed `n` is large, one possible way to proceed would be to approximate `log_n(2)` as 0, so the runtime multiplier would be approximated as 2 and the total runtime would be approximated as 8 minutes.

Alternately, since we probably know `n` to within an order of magnitude, another possibility would be to approximate the multiplier for a likely value of `n`:

- If `n` = 100 million, then we would approximate the multiplier as 2.075 and the total runtime as 8.30 minutes.
- If `n` = 1 billion, then we would approximate the multiplier as 2.067 and the total runtime as 8.27 minutes.
- If `n` = 10 billion, then we would approximate the multiplier as 2.060 and the total runtime as 8.24 minutes.

Note here that huge changes in our approximation of `n` yield pretty small changes in the approximation of the total runtime.

It's worth noting that, while this looks nice on paper, in practice architectural considerations can cause real-life runtimes to be much different from the ones we've calculated here. For instance, if the algorithm induces a bunch of paging after doubling the data size, the runtime could be much, much higher than the ~8 minutes we've approximated here.

Comment: This is nicely explained! Thanks a lot for your kind help! This question should be more tackled logically rather than mathematically, you balanced both our perfectly.

Comment: Note that the question doesn't even assume the algorithm is being run on a standard PC system, it might as well be a low-power embedded device which can barely sort a thousand items in 4 minutes.

Comment: @liori for sure, in which case the estimate would be 8.80 minutes, not a huge amount higher than the estimate with a billion items.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to calculate the absolute time, without knowing the value of n.
Take this through some empirical values.
Assume 'k' is the time taken for one single operation

```
If, n = 2, k.n.log(n) = 4   => k.2.1 = 4   => k = 2
  if n is doubled, k.2n.log(2n) = 2.4.2 => 16 minutes

If, n = 4, k.n.log(n) = 4   => k.4.2 = 4   => k = 1/2
  if n is doubled, k.2n.log(2n) = 1/2.8.3 => 12 minutes

If, n = 64, k.n.log(n) = 4   => k.64.6 = 4   => k = 1/96
  if n is doubled, k.2n.log(2n) = 1/96.128.7 => 9.33 minutes
```

So as n increases, the time taken comes closer to twice the time (8 minutes)

Comment: This is helpful! However, no input size is given, and the examiner requires an 'approximate value' - it's a rather ambiguous question

Answer (score 5):

The information provided is **incomplete**.

**Proof:**

Let the algorithmic complexity be `O(nlogn)`. This means the time taken, `t` = `c*nlogn`.

Therefore, we have the following equations:

- `4 = c*n*logn`
- `t = c*(n2)*log(n2)`, where `t` is the required answer
- `n2 = 2*n2`

Number of variables = 4 (`n`, `n2`, `t`, `c`)
Number of unique equations = 3
Since we need atleast 4 equations for 4 variables, the provided information is incomplete.

Comment: Indeed it is! Surprised how this made it's way into an exam. May I ask why do we introduce 'c'? We never actually worked out such problems, we only explained what time complexity is and how it varies from one algorithm to the other.

Comment: This is how the the Big-O complexity is defined. If an algorithm is O(f(n)), it means that the time taken is linearly proportional to `f(n)`. You can read more about it [here](http://www.careerbaba.in/interview-questions-answers/introduction-to-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm/).

Comment: Just a sidenote: The (exact!) complexity does not have to be c*n*log(n). O(n*log(n)) just says that there exists c > 0 and a n > 0 (might be veeeeery large) for which the actual complexity t(n) <= c*n*log(n). It might even be that t(8) is smaller than t(4), as long as eventually the upper condition holds.

Comment: Cheers everyone for your kind help!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an absolutely terrible exam question, probably written by someone who doesn't have a deep understanding of what Big-O notation is actually about.  There is a lot wrong with it - much of which has already been addressed in other answers.

The biggest problem is that Big-O notation doesn't give you any direct relationship to real time.  It throws out a huge amount of information that would be required to answer the actual question being asked.

The other answers here have pointed out that the question doesn't give you any indication of how many items were in the original set of inputs, only that there are twice as many in the second set, and that information is critical to giving an answer.  But there are a couple of things that they didn't mention...

First, Big-O ignores algorithm overheads.  It could be the case that the algorithm used actually takes 3.5 minutes to setup, regardless of how many inputs it receives, and that for the original set of inputs the actual processing time was only about 30 seconds.  That's going to seriously affect the calculation of time taken for any arbitrary number of inputs.

But as bad as that omission is, Big-O takes it even further.

Check out this quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Example):

> In typical usage, the formal definition of O notation is not used directly; rather, the O notation for a function f is derived by the following simplification rules:
>
> - If f(x) is a sum of several terms, the one with the largest growth rate is kept, and all others omitted.
> - If f(x) is a product of several factors, any constants (terms in the product that do not depend on x) are omitted.

What this means is that the time calculation can include multiple terms that are ultimately discarded.  What if the algorithm takes `c * (n + n * log(n))` time to complete, with no overhead?  In Big-O notation it's still `O(nlogn)`.

The only answer that is really possible to the exam question is "some time greater than 4 minutes."  We can't know anything more than that without a lot more information.  Specifically:

- What is the overhead?
- What's the time cost per operation?
- How many items are we talking about?
- What other terms have been elided?

Comment: That is true, the question is rather lacking. Unfortunately, these exams are required for entry into University, pretty surprised at the low standard for a nation wide exam. Thanks for taking your time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Amitoj's reasoning, but I'd generalize it.

Let `n0` = the number of elements that results in a run time of 4 mins, and `n1` = 2 * `n0`. Then we have

```
c = 4 mins / (n0 * log n0)
```

We are trying to find

```
t = c * n1 * log n1
  = 4 mins / (n0 * log n0) * n1 * log n1
  = 4 mins * (n1 / n0) * (log n1 / log n0)
```

`n1 / n0` is always = 2.

As n0 => infinity, the limit of `log n1 / log n0` goes to 1.

So yes, as n0 gets larger, the limit of t is `4 mins * 2 = 8 mins`.

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers, except of `Anmol Singh Jaggi` are wrong.

First of all it is easy to see that **this information is not enough to get an answer**. And this is why:

All you need to do is to solve an equation. If the time complexity of your algorithm is O(n logn), then the first equation you have is:

[image]

where `n` in the size of your list. If they want you to find how much time will it take you to finish the algorithm for size twice as big, they basically want to find `x`:

[image]

So basically you need to solve a system of 2 equations with 3 unknown. This have either 0 answers (not in our case) or infinite amount of answers.

---

Now you have to make assumption of your c1. If c1 = 1, then

[image]

Substituting n to the second equation you get: `x = 13.5`. So 13 and half a minute.

---

But one more time, this answer we got on assumption that c1 is equal to 1, if you have another constant factor, you will get another answer.

Comment: The challenge is working it out mentally...the exam does not allow the use of any sort of calculator...! Calculating that value of n would be rather difficult.

Comment: @XandruMifsud ok, if you think that providing a wrong value (with absolutely wrong solution) is a better option, then go ahead with your accepted solution. On the exam, it is enough to tell that you can't give an answer to a 3 unknown system of 2 equation. On the other hand you do not need 5 digit precision on the exam. And it is easy to see that the solution to `nlogn = 4` is somewhere between `2.5` and `3` (this can be done in 2 minutes). So select a 2.75 as a middle value. And it is not that hard to calculate `5.5 log 5.5`. So no need for any sort of calculator, you can do this in your head